# Prevent ng-if to print html template in angular js component

Tags: angularjs, components

I have the following component, I need in few places in the code do not show that component but I don't want to do that outside the component because I will need to add ng-if in different places to check if the status is 1  then do not show the directive.

how can I do that in the component? maybe do I need a controller and then don't print the HTML?

I do not want to use ng-if because I am trying to reduce the use of watchers also

component :

```
  .component('comp', {
        template: '<span class="class"><another-component></nother-component></span>' +
                  '<span class="status {{$ctrl.textClass}}" ng-bind-html="$ctrl.text" ></span>',
        bindings: {
            textClass : '<',
            text : '<'
            status : '<'
        }
    });
```

Comment: so add another `bindings` to the component to get current status and pass it from where you used the component to the inside component, and then use `ng-if` with that `status`

Comment: is it a good practice ? you mean to add the ng-id inside the component template and not outsise

Comment: that's what you ask for! this helps you to insert component in the views without `ng-if`, not?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject $element in your component's controller, then remove element based on some condition (whatever meets your specifications).

e.g.

```
  .component('someComponent', {
    controller: someComponentController,
    template: 'Hi'
  })

someComponentController.$inject = ['$element'];

function someComponentController($element) {
  const earthIsRounded = true;
  if (earthIsRounded) {
    $element.remove();
  }
}
```

[Some working fiddle you can play around with.](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ufx9hn/12/)